# Australia Post Tracking Number In Hotmail / Gmail

Tags: email, gmail, hotmail

In Hotmail / Gmail DHL and FedEx tracking numbers seem to be picked up from emails and put into a nice header on top of the email.

Is there documentation on how to format emails to make tracking numbers show in hotmail / gmail on the top?

Also, is this possible for other carriers like Australia Post?